# Dell Inspiron N5110 touchpad disabled but still working

Tags: touchpad, dell-inspiron

I closed touchpad from device settings. It's now showing disabled. But still working. Also I can not set with FN + keyboard combinations.

How to remove touchpad fully? Is there a way to remove it in command line?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted synaptics drive then install it again : http://www.synaptics.com/en/drivers.php
disable the touchpad with synaptics. It's worked.